# Select by username query does not work

Tags: php, mysql

This query is supposed to select `domain_name` where the username match, but its not working

```
$domain = $db->getAll("SELECT `domain_name` FROM `".PREFIX."domains` WHERE `custom_for` = ?i", $user->filter->username );
```

`custom_for` column have user's usernames, by the way `$user->filter->username` does echo user's username fine.

however at the same time if i select by user's id it does work

```
$domain = $db->getAll("SELECT `domain_name` FROM `".PREFIX."domains` WHERE `custom_for_id` = ?i", $user->filter->userid );
```

it select by user's uid it echo the results correct but with user's username it do not work, i want it to work with user's username.

What is wrong i am doing here ?

Thanks.

Comment: What are the field type of `custom_for`, `custom_for_id`

Comment: What means `but its not working`?

Comment: @RanaGhosh, varchar for custom_for and int for custom_for_id.

Comment: @Jens, sorry, could not understand the question ?

Comment: @Naby You say it is not working. But not working is not detailed enough to help you. Do you get an error or no records or too much records or ....

Comment: @Naby Can you give me the two query after building the query.

Comment: What database abstraction are you using, `getAll()` is neither `pdo` nor `mysqli`. What does `?i` mean? At a guess I'd say it was a placeholder and your `getAll()` method attempts to bind the "filter" as a parameter - I'd also guess that `i` denotes that it should be bound as an integer rather than a string... but this is all guesswork, there's not enough information to say for definite.

Comment: ... are you using PEAR's `DB_common` class?

Comment: You know that's defunct right? You should really be using PDO or, if you insist on a PEAR package, MDB2 : https://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.php

Comment: @CD001 it was ?i which were only for INT i had to replace it with ?s for string, i did not even noticed that thanks to Rana Ghosh for reminding me.

Comment: @jens, actually it were not giving any error at all even after enabling error reports of all kinds i don't know why this was bugging me from last 2 hours

Comment: @CD001 it's by http://phpfaq.ru/safemysql i don't know if its PEAR::DB

Comment: I'm pretty sure the guy that wrote that is a big SO user; he's seldom wrong so I'd assume you're pretty safe with that - not sure whether it's still maintained though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should change `i` to something which will work for **varchar**. OR set `custom_for` field as `int`, it will work.
`?i` is for INT type.

Comment: ok just found these lines from the devaloper 

 * ?s ("string")  - strings (also DATE, FLOAT and DECIMAL)
 * ?i ("integer") - the name says it all 
 * ?n ("name")    - identifiers (table and field names) 


changing ?i to ?s worked, i will accept this answer as you gave me the idea.